# How to use NSLock in a function?

Tags: objective-c, nslock

Is this the correct method to prevent more than one thread to access the function MyTaskF?

.h file:

```
@interface MyInterface  : NSObject {

//... some other stuff here

}
```

.m file:

```
static NSLock *mytaskMutex;

static MyInterface *MyInterfaceSingleton;

int MyTaskF(int iVar)
{

    [mytaskMutex lock];

    //do stuff in here

    [mytaskMutex unlock];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `mytaskMutex` so the calls to `lock` and `unlock` won't be made.

Comment: with the way the code is written, how to go initializing it the proper way?.thanks.

Comment: One way is to assign a value to `mytaskMutex` inside the `+ (void)initialize` method of the class.

Comment: will this do it? static NSLock * mytaskMutex = [[NSLock alloc] init];  How about using @synchronized method or dispatch method?. Performance wise the same?.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I think , the code is in the right direction. Thanks for the comment. If you a code suggestion, let me know.